# Pivot table filter raises error when empty

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot-table

.I have multiple pivot tables. When I open the workbook, I am forcing excel to select filters using:

```
Sheets("PSD").Select
'Update table 7 Number of PSDs scheduled by Month
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Adhoc").CurrentPage = _
    "No"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable7").PivotFields("Type").CurrentPage = _
    "PSD Inspection"
'Update table 8 Number of PSDs scheduled by Month
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Adhoc").CurrentPage = _
    "No"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Type").CurrentPage = _
    "PSD Inspection"
```

The problem is when there is no data with that filter as expected, I am getting an error.

How can I create a condition where I check if the filter exists and if it does, force the filter to what I want, else skip it.

Comment: The easiest way might be to add the line `On Error Resume Next` to the top of the script. This tells VBA to ignore an error if encountered, and move onto the next line.

Comment: Then the problem is if that filter does not exist, it forces to select the next available filter. how can I either not display it or maybe force to display the filter with ZERO?

Answer (score 0):

would getpivotdata work? getpivotdata will return an error for cases where the "index" doesn't exist or else 0 for cases where "index" exists but no data exists (or sums to 0)

instead of using getpivotdata in VBA itself, you might prefer to add a new worksheet with getpivotdata and other formulas that determine which filter you need, then refer to this worksheet in your VBA.

if you structure this properly, you could then change the rules / formula in this new worksheet to drive changes to the filtering logic without having to edit VBA - this will make troubleshooting easier also.